# How to install Jenkins with no internet access?

Tags: jenkins, centos7

I am working in an centos7 environment with no internet access, and I need to install Jenkins.

I pull the jenkins-2.141-1.1.noarch.rpm and transfer it to the offline machine and add the jenkins repo to the repo.d folder.

However when I run yum install jenkins, its asking for a GPG key? How do I get this if I am working on an offline machine?

Thanks

Comment: That's rather a rpm-issue and not a Jenkins issue, isn't it? You could simply download the jenkins-war and run it with "java -jar jenkins.war".

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions

Important Note on CentOS Java
Jenkins requires Java in order to run, however yum install jenkins does not enforce that java is already installed. Check to make sure that you already hava java installed by running java -version. To further make things difficult for CentOS users, the default CentOS version of Java is not compatible with Jenkins. Jenkins typically works best with a Sun implementation of Java, which is not included in CentOS for licensing reasons.